# In SQL Server, is TOP deterministic by default when used on a table with a clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I was trying to explain to some people why this query is a bad idea:

```
SELECT z.ReportDate, z.Zipcode, SUM(z.Sales) AS Sales,
COALESCE(
  (SELECT TOP (1) GroupName
  FROM dbo.zipGroups
  WHERE (Zipcode = z.Zipcode)), 'Unknown') AS GroupName,
COALESCE(
  (SELECT TOP (1) GroupCode
  FROM dbo.zipGroups
  WHERE (Zipcode = z.Zipcode)), 0) AS GroupNumber
FROM dbo.Report_ByZipcode AS z
GROUP BY z.ReportDate, z.Zipcode
```

and suggesting a better way to write it, when my boss ended the discussion with, "Well, it's been returning the right data for the last year and we haven't had any problems with it, so it's fine."

At which point I thought to myself, how in the world is that even possible?

After some digging, I discovered these facts:

1. This query is supposed to group sales by Zipcode and date, and link those to the largest Group (by population size) that a Zipcode is assigned to by way of the zipGroups table.
2. Each Zipcode can be assigned to 0 to many Groups, and if a Zipcode is assigned to 0 Groups, it's simply not in the zipGroups table.
3. A Group is a geographical area, and the GroupNumbers are ranked by largest to smallest by population (for example, the group covering the NY-NJ-CT tri-state area is GroupNumber 1, and North Platte, Nebraska is GroupNumber 209).
4. The zipGroups table has not changed in at least 2 years.
5. The zipGroups table has a clustered index with Zipcode, GroupNumber (ascending) as the keys.
6. The combination of Zipcode, GroupNumber is unique in zipGroups.

So my question has 2 parts.

A) Even though there are no ORDER BY clauses in those SELECT TOP queries, are they actually deterministic because the clustered index is basically providing it a default ORDER BY?

B1) If that is true, is the query, *however precariously*, actually doing what it's supposed to do?

B2) If that is not true, can you help me prove it?

Note: I've already re-written this to use joins, so I don't need the SQL to fix it, I need to get it into production so I stop worrying about it breaking.

Comment: Plain and simple: if there is no `ORDER BY` there is **no guarantee** for any order whatsoever

Comment: Tough problem: what to say to the boss that says "it's fine".

Comment: It is not logically deterministic even if from a practical perspective the query optimiser wouldn't currently do anything else. If you need a particular behaviour you should specify it otherwise next service pack/version your queries might break  (Usage of `TOP 100 PERCENT` in Views or using variables to concatenate strings spring to mind). It seems a completely pointless risk to take as there is no benefit to not being explicit.

Comment: @Martin - fair points. But there's another adage - if it ain't broke, don't fix it. If we can know that it works perfectly (such as the aggregate-nonaggregate-orderby MySql trick), who's to argue against the boss? It is quite inconceivable that this behaviour will change (for the specific question circumstances) because it is a very simple operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server makes no guarantees about the ordering of records in the absence of ORDER BY. It might yield the correct results 999,999 times and then fail on the millionth try. Don't do it.

Comment: oh, much more than 1 in a million

Comment: @cyberwiki: When you say "more", I'm not sure whether you are referring to the numerator or the denominator, and hence I can't tell what point your making (you could mean both, I suppose; depending on the circumstances, we could see failure_rate >>> 1e-6 or failure_rate <<< 1e-6).

Answer (score 2):

Always use an order by with a TOP statement. The order is not guaranteed to be in the order of the clustered index as demonstrate in this blog post (complete with a query that disproves it):

[Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx).

Even if it did go by the clustered index, I wouldn't write queries that depend on undocumented behavior of the DB engine and it is better to be explicit for readability.

Comment: the linked article and several other deal with the situation when the optimizer has a *choice* as to what index to use. If given only 1 choice and TOP N is fixed at N=1, it is far more predictable.

Comment: That's why I upvoted your answer. Still I think it is a bad idea to rely on undocumented behavior of the query optimizer, even if it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're relying on a clustered index rather than the collation, then getting the right order is coincidental, not deterministic.

In the real world, indexes can be changed from one kind to another, for good reasons, bad reasons, or no reason at all.  And, in the real world, you don't necessarily get to choose which index SQL Server will use in executing a query. (Or whether it will use an index at all.)

Technically, the collation can also be changed for good reasons, bad reasons, or no reason at all. But everybody *knows* changing the collation will change the sort order--that's its job, after all--so it's not a surprise. (Ever heard of "the principle of least surprise"?)

Answer (score 1):

The link by JohnFx is good, although long and hard to follow.  Here's a small snippet on it's own that will show the data returning in non-clustered index order.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (x INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, z INT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO t1 (x,z) VALUES (1,4);
INSERT INTO t1 (x,z) VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO t1 (x,z) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO t1 (x,z) VALUES (4,1);

SELECT x, z FROM t1;
```

Output (you should get)

```
x           z
----------- -----------
4           1
2           2
3           3
1           4
```

The execution plan shows it using the Unique (or other) index instead of the clustered index.

**Even if** the clustered index is chosen, it may not sort correctly if the data is being merged from parallelism, if the TOP N count is high enough.

Having said that, since you are only using TOP(1) *and* if the table has *only one index* available, it can be ***considered deterministic*** since it will only use that index and pick the first entry in the index pages.

Comment: So - since this query is "considered deterministic", he should inform his boss that "it's fine" is true?

Comment: @David - yes, in this instance in all current implementations of SQL Server up to 2008 R2

Comment: How confident are you that ["Advanced Scanning"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475.aspx) can't apply here?

Comment: @Martin - absolutely confident. A TOP(1) from a clustered index (my stated assumption that it is the only index available) doesn't fit "full table scan required" criteria to trigger Advanced Scanning. On top of that, add a 80% confidence (wild guess) that the edition in question is not Enterprise.

Comment: @Richard - But as far as the scan iterator is concerned it might be considered a full table scan. The `TOP` is enforced by a different iterator in the plan. I don't have Enterprise SKU to play with here.

Comment: @Martin guess if either of us makes MVP we can look at the source (code)

Answer (score 0):

> A) Even though there are no ORDER BY clauses in those SELECT TOP queries, are they actually deterministic because the clustered index is basically providing it a default ORDER BY?
>   B1) If that is true, is the query, however precariously, actually doing what it's supposed to do?

When top is specified without ordering, the ordering is a side effect of the method of access chosen by the query optimizer.  Since the query optimizer would use the clustered index to resolve this query, you get a quite nice side effect.

I wouldn't use the word deterministic, as the query optimizer might not be deterministic.  However in the case where the optimizer choses the clustered index, yes - the query does what it is supposed to do.

ORDER should still be specified, so as to lock the correctness into the query.  One should separate correctness ("What do you want") and implementation ("How do you get it") into query and optimizer plan, respectively.

> B2) If that is not true, can you help me prove it?

Assuming there are more columns in the ZipGroups table, a Nonclustered index containing the only two relevant columns could be added that **would be preferred** over the clustered index.  If the nonclustered index had a different ordering (Zipcode asc, GroupNumber desc), then the query would break.

Comment: `you get a quite nice side effect` not 100% true. Even if a clustered index is picked, it is no guarantee of order (on that index)

Comment: Of course there's no guarantee. But there is -some- implementation there, and that implementation would be strange if it behaved differently (parallelism, of course, is always strange).